# Get post related to current post

Tags: wp-query

I add meta box in mobile CPT, Where I add a post with Ajax successfully. Here is code

```
function metabox_for_select2() {
add_meta_box( 'rudr_select2', 'My metabox', 'display_select2_metabox', 'mobile', 'normal', 'default' );
}

function display_select2_metabox( $post_object ) {
$html = '';
$appended_posts = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'select2_posts',true );
$html .= '<p><label for="select2_posts">Posts:</label><br /><select id="select2_posts" name="select2_posts[]" multiple="multiple">';

if( $appended_posts ) {
    foreach( $appended_posts as $post_id ) {
        $title = get_the_title( $post_id );
        $title = ( mb_strlen( $title ) > 50 ) ? mb_substr( $title, 0, 49 ) . '...' : $title;
        $html .=  '<option value="' . $post_id . '" selected="selected">' . $title . '</option>';
    }
}
$html .= '</select></p>';

echo $html;
}
```

Now after adding posts to meta box when I open a post, I need to show all those posts, where meta box have this post.

This query shows all post which I added to meta box on different posts not the specific. How to manage query after that its show recommended result.

```
<?php   
    $posts = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'select2_posts', true );
    $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'post_type' => 'mobile',
     'post__in' => $posts
 );

$results = new WP_Query($args);
while ($results->have_posts()) {
    $results->the_post();
    the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata();           
?>
```

How to get those posts where meta box have this post or link?

I am using this query on `single.php` and trying to show all post here where meta box has this post.

**Example:**

Add 2 Custom Post Type = `mobile` & `processor`

processor have 2 posts = `Nvidia` , `Intel`

mobile have 2 posts = `Apple` , `Nokia`

Add a meta box `select2_posts` to CPT `mobile`

After that, Apple using Nvidia processor & Nokia using Intel processor so add processor to meta box.

> Finaly Here Attached nvidia to Apple & intel to Nokia inside meta box

**Now** i want when i open Nvidia post in sidebar Apple mobile show & when i open Intel post in sidebar Nokia mobile show.

In simple word show those mobile which use this processor which i currently open.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your question, you are trying to do a meta query. You can do this by the following arguments:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10, 
    'post_type' => 'mobile',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'select2_posts',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' =>  $value_here
        )
    )
);
```

You can read more about meta queries [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).

Comment: Problem with your query it get all the post. But i need only those post where open/current post added

Comment: @Farooq Hi. Unfortunately i can't understand your question well... I've read your question a few times. Can you add an example to your question so i can understand it?

Comment: please check example. I attached it to the question